# excel pivot table data with percentage c#

Tags: c#, vba, excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to create dynamic pivot tables,data comes from web service and fills to data sheet,then I'm creating pivot table with that data range.

I'm able to create pivot table but eventhough in data sheet some data's look like 10%,20% and format type is percentage , in pivot table values look like 0.10 , 0.20.

Is there any way to prevent excel's behaviour? Pivot table must show the values exactly like in data sheet.

Answer (score 0):

right click on the values you want to format in the pivot table.
Choose field settings
In the dialogue click number formatting to set the display format.
 then

right click onthe pivot table and choose pivot table options check that "preserve cell formatting on update is ticked"

(this let to set explicitly what formatting to use on the pivot table.  Note that when created it inherits the formatting from the cells it is based on, but it sounds like it's lost (or never had) this link.

Done.

Comment: thanks for help but this is not helpful for my problem,I have dynamic data,it can be change any time. 
also i have to solve this programmaticly.
I just want to see the pivot table data's format exactly as data sheet's.

Comment: When you create the pivot table programatically does it not  inhert the formatting?  In my experiments it did.  If you subsequently chnage the data with data that has a different type, do you recreate the pivot.  I need more info to help more.

Comment: when i m creating pivot programatically it does not inherit the formatting,even though data is 20% and numberFormat = percentage , in pivot table it looks like 0.20 and and numberFormat = general

Comment: Ah.  The PT will only inherit the formatting for fields in the row and column areas.  Fields in the values need to have formatting manually applied - or in your case with code.

Comment: I just tried with power pivot and you don't get any other options either.  I think you will need to write code to change the format of the field depending on the format of the data that you have just loaded .

Comment: I think you are right and it is disturbing.Thank you for help.

Comment: Please flag my answer as an answer... You just need to write or record code to do it now...